# How to Show Message when reached to date

Tags: android, countdown

I am writing a small CountDown program, and i found one of the SO link helpful for me to get code, but i have a small query How to show Message when countdown reached to date we mentioned.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String time1 = "14-02-2015 12:01:00";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();  
            String time = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";

            String dateStart =(String) DateFormat.format(time, start);                          
            String dateStop = time1;


             SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
            // Custom date format
            java.util.Date d1=null;
            java.util.Date d2=null;
              try {
                    d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
                    d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffdays    =(diff/ (1000*60*60*24));
            long diffHours = ((diff - (1000*60*60*24*diffdays)) / (1000*60*60));                             
            long diffMinutes = (diff - (1000*60*60*24*diffdays) - (1000*60*60*diffHours)) / (1000*60);  
            long diffSeconds =(diff - (1000*60*60*24*diffdays) - (1000*60*60*diffHours) -(1000*60*diffMinutes))/ (1000);                

            String out= 
                    "Days: "+diffdays+
                    " Hours: "+diffHours+
                    " Minutes: "+diffMinutes+
                    " seconds: "+diffSeconds;
            tv.setText(out);

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000); 
  }
}
```

I want to show message "Happy Valentines Day" in same TextView when reached to date

Comment: You don't want to do this. (You can't do this, really.) Set an alarm using `AlarmManager` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to run a countdown timer days together

If it is to set on particular date,you may need to add an alarm event with some custom message on that specific date.
Also you have to write a broadcast receiver to handle that alarm to open some activity and handle there.

Answer (score 0):

You have countdown in android:

Example:

```
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer( a.getTime() - b.getTime(), 1000)
            {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                    long minutes = seconds / 60;
                    long hours = minutes / 60;
                    long days = hours / 24;

                    txtDays.setText( days + "" );
                    txtHours.setText( hours % 24 + "h" );
                    txtMinutes.setText( minutes % 60 + "m" );
                    txtSeconds.setText( seconds % 60 + "s");
                }

                public void onFinish()
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    txtDateTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtDays.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtSeconds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtMinutes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtDayText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.start();
```